# sort objects, some should always be first

Tags: php, sorting

I have a collection of country objects that look like this:

```
class country {
    public $uid;
    public $name;
}
```

Now I should sort them. One country with id == 999 should always be first in the collection, the rest should be sorted by name. So, I thought usort should actually do the trick, but the sorting is not correct. I tried this:

```
function mySortCallback($a, $b) {
    if($a->uid == 999 || $b->uid == 999) return 1;
    return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
}

usort($myCollection, 'mySortCallback');
```

Comment: Ok. Saying that something should be **first** is very unspecific. Better would be to say that it should be **smaller** than every other value. Because it depends own how you sort: from lowest to highest or from highest to lowest. If you say the element should be *first* than it has to be smaller than anything else in the first case and bigger in the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php):

> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.0 if they are equal.

Try this:

```
private function mySortCallback($a, $b) {
    if ($a->uid == 999)
        return -1;
    elseif ($b->uid == 999)
        return 1;
    else
        return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it, I´ll accept your answer as soon as the system allows me to do so. ;)

Comment: I would suggest adding one condition if they both are `== 999` so it returns 0.  That way all conditions are covered...

Comment: ircmaxell that's case is undefined. I thought about it but, doing what you propose could end up not having the countries with id==999 at the beginning. This depends on the implementation of the sorting algorithm.

Comment: Well, no, they would still be at the beginning since they are "greater" than everything else.  Perhaps just a first condition: `if ($a->uid == $b->uid && $a->uid == 999) return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);`.  That way, all 999's will be at the top of the list and sorted by name.  But then again, the OP said one country, so in either case it may be moot...

Comment: @ircmaxell if I understand the requirement that uid=999 should come first, then sorted by name (for all uid's), that condition is wrong; a correct one would be: `return ($a->uid != $b->uid && ($a->uid == 999 || $b->uid == 999) ? ($a->uid == 999 ? -1 : 1) : strcmp($a->name, $b->name));`

Comment: @pakore your example will not sort the items with uid=999 by name, which I assume is needed.

Comment: @manixrock well, you are assuming it. The problem with assumptions is that they may be wrong. For me that case is undefined, as it was not stated in the question as a requirement. The user accepted the solution so I assume ;) that he is happy with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The line

`if($a->uid == 999 || $b->uid == 999) return 1;`

can't be correct in my opinion.

Try to exchange it to check whether actually just one of the two has `uid==999` and return the value according to which of them has value 999.